# How to use Task to run not static method with delay

Tags: c#, task

I am wonder how to use Tasks to achieve goal: start method with parameter (method is not static) with 2 seconds delay, but user can cancel that Task before it starts.

I provide sample code from mobile application, where are to methods:

- DoWork which is doing 'something' if Task is not cancelled.
- OnTouch which is listening for user Touch on device screen. When user is touching screen first time MotionEvent.Down occurs only once, then if he will move his finder (do MotionEvent.Move) or pull his finder (do MotionEvent.Up) within 2 seconds he won't start Task which will run DoWork method.

This is my example:

```
private void DoWork(string abc)
{
    MyItem.Text = abc;
}

public bool OnTouch(MotionEvent e)
{
 switch (e.Action)
    {
        case MotionEvent.Down:
            // start task with 2 seconds delay
        break;
        case MotionEvent.Move:
            // cancel task
        break;
        case MotionEvent.Up:
            // cancel task
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with other answers that you should use `Task.Delay` and `CancellationToken`. However, I recommend that you use `await` instead of `ContinueWith`:

```
private void DoWork(string abc)
{
  MyItem.Text = abc;
}

private async Task DoWorkWithDelayAsync(string abc, CancellationToken token)
{
  try
  {
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), token);
  }
  catch (OperationCanceledException)
  {
    // TODO: add a notification that the task did *not* run.
  }
  DoWork(abc);
}

private CancellationTokenSource cts;
public bool OnTouch(MotionEvent e)
{
  switch (e.Action)
  {
    case MotionEvent.Down:
      cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
      var _ = DoWorkWithDelayAsync("", cts.Token);
      break;
    case MotionEvent.Move:
    case MotionEvent.Up:
      if (cts != null)
        cts.Cancel();
      break;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: It's easier (less code) that @Jodrell solution and provide same functionality. For me it's good.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something similar.

First add a `CancellationTokenSource` property in your class (cancelToken) and initialize it

```
var cancelToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
```

then

```
switch (e.Action)
    {
        case MotionEvent.Down:
            Task.Delay(2000, cancelToken.Token).ContinueWith(() => DoSomething(),TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());   
        break;
        case MotionEvent.Move:
            cancelToken.Cancel(false);
        break;
        case MotionEvent.Up:
             cancelToken.Cancel(false);
        break;
    }
```

in DoSomething function wrap your code with

```
 if(!cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
 {

 }
```

Comment: You are creating two different tasks in MotionEvent.Down - the second one will start without delay, and the first one has no cancellation source.

Comment: @RufusL yes, this will create new task each time. To avoid it I should add a Task property that the method should check before execute it

Comment: Yeah, it will create 2 new tasks each time - one that does nothing for 2 seconds, and another that does the work right away. Replacing `; Task.Factory.StartNew` with `.ContinueWith` and passing the cancelToken to the `Delay` method should work, I think.

Comment: It won't compile, because we can't convert lambda expression to type 'System.Threading.Tasks.IContinuation' beacuse it'snt a delegate type.

Comment: I've added a parameter to ContinueWith method, let me know if now works

Comment: @faby I use `state => { DoSomething(); }` and there is no error. Just checking if it's working fine.

Comment: @boski let me know if you need more help I'm here

Comment: @faby It's fired always. There is no way to cancel that with `cancelToken.Cancel(false);`. I've check that and it's fired before 2 seconds ends. So delay is not working well.

Comment: It's maybe because `Task.Delay(2000);` creates an async task that will complete after a 2 seconds, but the execution of the current method will continue in parallel.

Comment: Anyway I don't know how to fix that. Method DoSomething is fired always without delay.

Comment: @faby sorry, but is not working still. It run DoSomething() everytime I go with MotionEvent.Down, and never reach `!cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested`